# Multidimensional arrays

Tags: php, loops, multidimensional-array

I have a php multidimensional array which looks like this:

```
$fields = array( array('input', 'title', 'slug', 'keywords'), 
     array('textarea', 'content'), 
     array('radio', 'active', 'active2', 'active3', 'active4', 'active5')
);
```

and I am accessing the array, like this.

However because some arrays contain more values than others I am having trouble, as you can see below $type < 2...how do I fix this?

```
for($type = 0; $type < 2; $type++) {
    for($field = 0; $field < 2; $field++) {
        echo $fields[$type][$field];
    }
}
```

Comment: Good formatting is your friend.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use a [`foreach`](http://php.net/control-structures.foreach):

```
foreach ($fields as $values)
{
   foreach ($values as $value) 
   {
       echo $value;
   }
}
```

Comment: Also, he can use `count($array)` to find out how many items there are in `$array` if this is needed for some other purpose.

Comment: Why did I not think to loop inside a loop?? Thanks, all sorted now! :D

Comment: Another tip: you can also create a reference to a value within a foreach loop. This is useful when you are modifying the values in an array. Example:

foreach ($array as &$value)
{
   $value = 'something else';
}

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`array_walk_recursive`](http://php.net/function.array-walk-recursive):

```
<?php
    array_walk_recursive($fields, 'echo');
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

[`count()`](http://php.net/function.count) is giving you the number of items in an array:

```
for($type = 0; $type < count($fields); $type++) {
    for($field = 0; $field < count($fields[$type]); $field++) {
        echo $fields[$type][$field];
    }
}
```

Often [`foreach`](http://php.net/control-structures.foreach) is easier to use and will create code that you can change easier.